# Losing url when routing in angular

Tags: angular, routes

Im having difficulties with routing in angular in certain project.

Here is the function from certain component. After subscribing to currentCounter$ stream and taking value from it I need to pass it down to router, which takes me to another component.

```
onEditAutomaticCounter() {

this.isAutomaticCounterEditing = true;

    this.counterSubscription = this.currentCounter$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((currentCounter) => {
      console.log(currentCounter);
      this.router.navigate(['search', 'AutomaticCounter', currentCounter.Id], {
        relativeTo: this.route,
        queryParams: { currentCounterId: currentCounter.Id },
      });
    });
  }
```

Route from there is catched here and everything works but Im losing the URL adress that I need to have at the end of navigation because there is certain ID that I'll have to use later.

Something is reseting route, because there is a moment in which I see right url on adress bar and right after it dissapears and Im ending up with this URL `http://localhost:4200/#/search` and I need to have `http://localhost:4200/#/search/AutomaticCounters/params=.....`

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { key: '' },

    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'main', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch: 'full' },

      {
        path: 'search',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/main/main.module').then((m) => m.MainModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'search/AutomaticCounter/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/main/main.module').then((m) => m.MainModule),
      },
      { path: 'watchers', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/watchers/watchers.module').then((m) => m.WatchersModule) },
      { path: 'counters', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/counters/counters.module').then((m) => m.CountersModule) },
      { path: 'management', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/management/management.module').then((m) => m.ManagementModule) },
    ],
  },

  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { key: 'login' } },

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }, // ustawiamy login jako startowy, żeby załadowały się style mpcore
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
      enableTracing: false,
    }),
    StoreModule.forFeature(ROUTER_FEATURE_KEY, routerReducer),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      stateKey: ROUTER_FEATURE_KEY,
      routerState: RouterState.Minimal,
      serializer: CustomRouterSerializer,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I know that there are two same Lazy Modules, but I dont know how to do it different. It's the way that this project have been written. It would be perfect If I could add another children in this fragment :

```
    {
        path: 'search',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/main/main.module').then((m) => m.MainModule),

children: [...]
      },
```

But sommething like that won't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was another this.router.navigate(['/search']) in ngOnInit hook at search component which casues url to change again.